# CoreApplication.Id vs. ASHWID vs Package.Current.Id

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Can anyone tell me the difference between these 3 IDs?

I want to identify a particular installation (per purchase/device and not counting minor updates) of my win8 app, which of them will best fit my need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need two of them:

- App Specific Hardware ID (ASHWID) contains information about the device (it does not necessarily match the purchase since the latter is attached to a user account). Also you will probably need to account for the hardware drift as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx).
- [`Package.Current.Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.packageid.aspx) identifies your application, including its complete version, so you'll need to ignore the parts which you allow to change with minor updates.

EDIT:
I don't think `CoreApplication.Id` will be any use to you. It is only unique within a package to differentiate between multiple application within a single package. I don't think you van edit it through VS designer, but you can see the value if you open the `appxmanifest` file in editor, e.g.:

```
<Package>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" />
```

It's probably best documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211415.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to identify a device, ASHWID is the way to go (you might want to use it in combination with a Device Guid generated on the user local storage to ease server lookup of the known device ASHWID)

If you want to identify a purchase you definitely want to take a look at CurrentApp.GetAppReceiptAsync (and similar methods) . http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/jj649137.aspx

You can also use combination of the two depending on your scenario.

Comment: I like that bit about GetAppReceipt, very informational. Can you also modify the answer a little to include the diff between CoreApplication.Id vs. Package.Current.Id? Thanks.

Comment: @Alwyn I added more info on `CoreApplication.Id` to my answer.